# Why does my Rheem Performance Plus Gas Water Heater make a clicking sound just until water is running hot?

Tags: water, heater, noise

Our relatively new Rheem Performance Plus Gas Water Heater makes a clicking noise when you first turn on the hot water. Once the water has reached the correct temperature the clicking stops.

When I stand beside the heater while this is happening sounds like is coming from the pipe above but this may be just due to the way the sound is traveling.  I tried draining in case was due to air block or sediment did not help.

I did read something that said this could be the igniter relighting until water reaches correct temperature, can't seem to find that article again.  My brother in law has exact same heater doesn't happen with his.

Heater is functioning just fine.  I am almost sure it did not happen when we initially installed, it was a few days before I noticed.  Only thing that changed was I added the insulation to the hot water out pipe.

Any assistance greatly appreciated, driving me a little nuts.

Comment: What do you mean by "first turn on the hot water"? Like when you open a hot water tap or like when you ignite the pilot light? Is this an instant-hot or a traditional 40/50 gallon tank?

Comment: When I first turn on the tap.  Once water is flowing hot from the tap clicking stops.  Feels like once cold/tepid water is pushed from pipes to sink/shower and is hot all the way clicking stops.  it is a traditional 40 gal tank.

Comment: I suppose would be more correct to just say "any time I turn on the tap when hot water has not been flowing for a while" .  Clicking starts and then stops once water reaches correct temp.  If we don't run any hot water for a while and turn on the tap again, same thing happens, clicking for a bit and then stops when water flowing hot.

Comment: Probably expansion in the pipes as the water heats them up, they can slip where attached and click/tick,etc. It can be hard to tell where sounds like that are coming from.  I have hydronic heating (in floor) and I can always tell when a certain zone kicks on because of the ticking (expansions of the pipes) and they are pex!  It could also be some part of the WH that is somewhat loose, allowing it to move and tick away as it expands.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson I think you could be right. New water heater was a little taller than the old so had to cut the cold in/hot out pipes a bit, and positions were a little different.  So putting some more pressure on joints above due to slight angle.

Comment: I agree with @GeorgeAnderson. I have baseboard water heating and my copper pipes will snap, crackle, and pop until the pipes have reached the correct temperature. Unfortunately, the call for heat will usually be satisfied by then and so I get to listen to it all over again as things cool down. It's great for people who hate to sleep peacefully!

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I am pretty sure now my issue is similar, except thankfully only happens when tap/shower is turned on and til water runs hot, so little chance of interrupting sleep. I played around with the pipes a bit over the weekend and think I managed to eliminate noise when just running to sink on same floor, still have to look at when pushing water up above. May need to live with that tho, might require pulling up hardwood floorboards etc to resolve.